# How to integrate and test PayPal in an MVC4 website: do I really need to expose my dev environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have read through a lot of PayPal questions on here, and a lot of various pages online, but am very confused. I have found a few examples of the various types of payment, but many are quite old and I am not sure how relevant they are anymore as I have been told there have been recent changes. Unfortunately there does not seem to be any useful examples or documentation on the developer/sandbox PayPal site, or I just can't find them!

I am wondering if anyone can point me to some good examples, documentation or tutorials which would help me with the following:

Am I correct in thinking that if I wish to do any post-processing with a PayPal transaction, i.e. update the transaction in my database (sucess, etc), that I need to use IPN/PDT and that to use these I need to expose a listener to PayPal?

If this is true I am confounded as to how so many developers could use this system as I really cannot imagine exposing my dev/testing environment to the outside world in order to test and debug. I even watched a video where this was done on the asp.net website that did just that http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-22-restructuring-rerouting-and-paypal This is not something I can really consider in my work environment.

I am also struggling to find any documentation or examples as to what is actually returned to me when I specify the url for IPN. At the moment I am assuming it is something like `myurl.com/?item=blah&item1=blah&item2=foo` etc, but this is not specified anywhere I can find. The items returned are also not specified. At the moment I am assuming I can access the items as form data, but have no examples of this (except an MVC1 example in the above video).

I also believe that I need to use IPN, as PDT may not even get passed back if the user uses a credit card and then does not click the return to seller's website button. Is this true?

All I want to do is place a button on my web page, which will allow a user to pay for an annual subscription. I want to pass a unique transaction id to PayPal, which they will return to me, stating success or failure. I will then update my database so that the user will receive their subscription.

I had thought that doing this had been bad enough when I did it for SagePay (our current provider - we are only changing to be able to take international payments without having different currency bank accounts), but PayPal seems to be even worse. For SagePay I just had to change the URL I submitted to, from testing to live. Simple, they sent me back an encrypted response and actually had documentation as to exactly what was in the response.

I am really hoping that I have just got the wrong end of the stick here and that there is a sensible way to integrate PayPal into my website. At the moment it seems I am going to have to set up a URL on my current live service that PayPal can access, and then debug the live server to see exactly what I receive and to debug my code. This seems very wrong.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

PayPal is actually better than most in terms of enabling you to do testing. There's a complete testing sandbox solution ([support document](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/)), and when adding/editing your REST API application, you can click the "Edit" link next to "App Redirect URLs" and specify both a testing URL and live URL for production. That should give you everything you need to test locally without exposing your site to the outside world.

If it does end up giving you fits over using localhost, there's always services like [localtest.me](http://readme.localtest.me), that can let you get around it.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look into Paypal's official site: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/
They have a very details explanations. Follow their instruction step by step. Ask question when you actually meet problems.

Another site I once used before is :http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/84538/Setting-up-PayPal-Instant-Payment-Notification-IPN

And for your questions:
 "Do I need to expose a listener to PayPal?" 
Yes, you need. Paypal has tutorial on this part in C# also.

"PDT may not even get passed back" 
Maybe. But IPN also has a miss chance.